# Issue when migrate Spring Boot 2.2.6 to Spring Boot 2.3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:81) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:67) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:167) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at sh.platform.template.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1716) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1272) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

That is my demo code: https://github.com/platformsh-templates/spring-mvc-maven-mongodb/tree/update_template

I googled it, however, I did not find the issue on this migration.

Comment: You are using deprecated classes such as AbstractMongoConfiguration  from Spring (https://github.com/platformsh-templates/spring-mvc-maven-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/sh/platform/template/MongoConfig.java#L11). Try changing that implementation before migrating to Spring Boot 2.3.0 (You are missing beans references)

Comment: You're looking the wrong branch, I'm working on this one: 
https://github.com/platformsh-templates/spring-mvc-maven-mongodb/tree/update_template/src/main/java/sh/platform/template
As you can see there is not this class, I've moved to `application.properties`

The branch name is: `update_template`

https://github.com/platformsh-templates/spring-mvc-maven-mongodb/tree/update_template

Comment: AbstractMongoConfiguration was deprecated and removed from Spring 2.3.0. AbstractMongoClientConfiguration is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Missed beans from *spring-data-mongodb*.
In your pom.xml, replace:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

By:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```